# How to keep curved borders using css 3

Tags: html, css

Border-radius style is not working for below code

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#description">Limerick One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#usage">Limerick Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#download">Limerick Three</a></li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS:**

```css
.menu { padding: 0; clear: both; border-radius:10px; }
.menu li { display: inline; }

.menu li a {
    padding: 6px; float:left;font-family:Gill, Helvetica, sans-serif;  border-right: 1px solid #000; border-bottom: none;
    text-decoration: none; color: #fff; font-weight: bold;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 0%, rgb(34,34,34) 54%, rgb(68,68,68) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 0%, rgb(34,34,34) 54%, rgb(68,68,68) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 0%, rgb(34,34,34) 54%, rgb(68,68,68) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 0%, rgb(34,34,34) 54%, rgb(68,68,68) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(68,68,68) 0%, rgb(34,34,34) 54%, rgb(68,68,68) 100%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0, rgb(68,68,68)),
        color-stop(0.54, rgb(34,34,34)),
        color-stop(1, rgb(68,68,68))
    );
}

.menu li.active a  { 
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(138,25,25) 0%, rgb(186,52,52) 54%, rgb(138,25,25) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(138,25,25) 0%, rgb(186,52,52) 54%, rgb(138,25,25) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(138,25,25) 0%, rgb(186,52,52) 54%, rgb(138,25,25) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(138,25,25) 0%, rgb(186,52,52) 54%, rgb(138,25,25) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(138,25,25) 0%, rgb(186,52,52) 54%, rgb(138,25,25) 100%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left bottom,
        left top,
        color-stop(0, rgb(138,25,25)),
        color-stop(0.54, rgb(186,52,52)),
        color-stop(1, rgb(138,25,25))
    );
}

.content {
    float: left; clear: both;
    background: #fff; padding: 10px 20px 20px; width: 400px;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avkKL/

Comment: In which browser? Where is the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Children of an element with a `border-radius` will always bleed out of their parent](http://jsfiddle.net/sPJC2/).

You have to set the `border-radius` directly on the elements you want to be rounded:

```css
.menu li:first-child a { border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px }
.menu li:last-child a  { border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0 }
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avkKL/1/

Answer (score 0):

```css
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

Add the webkit and moz prefixes. Not all versions of Chrome/Firefox/Safari respect the non-prefixed property.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a border set for .menu and there is no height because of the content. Radius sets the radius of the border but a border must exist for it to work.

For example, add `border:1px solid; height:24px` to .menu.

Comment: after adding border and height , border was curved under the menu, menu is still rectangle

Comment: @PHP - I was not suggesting my example was the solution. I was showing you that the radius works when you supply the proper properties. I am wondering whether you are using a doctype or not, too.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

Comment: @PHP - It doesn't matter to this problem but your doctype is for XHTML that is served as XML which you probably aren't doing and you shouldn't be using that doctype.